# Complexity of sorting algorthms

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, sorting

I've read an [article (German)](http://www.enterag.ch/hartwig/order/implementation.pdf) about different sorting algorithms where the author states this:

> [Smoothsort] is a sorting algorithm that uses swaps to sort and does not need any extra external allocated memory. Because of this it can't be stable, because if it was, it needed $O(n^2)$ comparisons in the worst case. (This statement is a hypothesis of mine. I'm very sure it holds, although I have yet to show it)

I wasn't able to find an algorithm on my own that satisfies the criteria (in-place, stable, faster than $O(n^2)$ in the worst case). Is that hypothesis true? If yes, how can one show that it holds?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  There is an O(*n* log *n*)-time comparison-based stable in-place sorting algorithm [Tra77].

[Tra77] Luis Trabb Pardo.  Stable sorting and merging with optimal space and time bounds.  *SIAM Journal on Computing*, 6(2):351–372, June 1977.  http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0206025

Answer (score 3):

The wikipedia page on [stable sorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability) pointed to [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.54.8381) description of a stable inplace mergesort that is supposed to be easy to understand